# How to take a thousand random samples in R?

Tags: r, loops, random

I've read [How to create a loop for generate a list of random samples in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9832268/how-to-create-a-loop-for-generate-a-list-of-random-samples-in-r)

I've scoured the internet for the answer to this question, but I just get generic loop problems.

I want to generate 5000 random uniform samples using `sample` and store them in a vector. I'm out of ideas so I'm coming here for help, my code:

```
Tests = NULL

for(i in c(1:5000)) { 
   Tests[i]<- sample(x = c(0:9), size = 50128, replace = T) 
   Record<-table(Tests)
}
```

I get the error:

> In Tests[i] <- sample(x = c(0:9), size = 50128, replace = T) :
>   number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

At least 50 times (probably 5000 times). I've tried changing the size of the sample, the number of samples,but nothing seems to get rid of this error. I'm trying to store all the samples in a table titled `Record`.

edit: I know how to make loops using `apply`/`sapply`/`lapply`, but I don't think that those would be good options for generating a ton of random samples because I don't think you could store them anywhere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unless you really need them, it's easiest not to store the numbers you generate any longer than you need, as there will be 250640000 of them, taking about a Gb of memory. Instead, you can just call `table` immediately on them. Using `replicate` instead of a `for` loop (you're not using `i` anyway) will put the results into a nice matrix for you too:

```
Record <- replicate(5000, table(sample(x = 0:9, size = 50128, replace = T)))

Record[, 1:10]
##   [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
## 0 4999 4971 4919 5116 5101 5016 4861 5109 5063  4991
## 1 5060 4959 4935 5047 5142 4927 5005 4920 5098  5023
## 2 4916 4954 5019 4966 4994 4954 5049 5013 5031  5081
## 3 4907 5007 5075 5042 4993 5015 5078 5037 4936  5073
## 4 5117 4935 5003 5000 4970 5084 5008 4948 5115  5010
## 5 4966 5146 5054 4944 5048 4935 5016 5104 5042  5010
## 6 5055 4899 4964 5006 4977 5076 4943 5048 5064  4817
## 7 5082 5040 5070 5034 4976 5056 5049 5012 4985  4983
## 8 5094 5108 5014 4949 5052 5037 5073 5000 4894  5082
## 9 4932 5109 5075 5024 4875 5028 5046 4937 4900  5058
```

If you really need to store the numbers as well, you can use a similar approach:

```
# Make a matrix of terms. Warning: big.
Terms <- replicate(5000, sample(x = 0:9, size = 50128, replace = T))

# Apply table to each column (set of samples)
Record <- apply(Terms, 2, table)
```

Alternately, if you're storing the samples, instead of using `replicate` you could just sample directly into a matrix:

```
Terms <- matrix(sample(x = 0:9, size = 50128 * 5000, replace = T), nrow = 50128)
Record <- apply(Terms, 2, table)
```

`Record` (and `Terms`, if stored) will look the same regardless, though the time required may vary.

Answer (score 12):

Your problem isn't with `sample()`, but with storing the results in an object that is `NULL`.  This works fine (albeit slowly since we're storing a 5000 by 50000 object):

```
Tests <- list()
for(i in 1:5000) { 
    Tests[[i]] <- sample(x = c(0:9), size = 50128, replace = TRUE) 
}
```

However, `table(Tests)` is going to fail because `table` applied to a list tries to *cross-classify* the list, e.g.

```
table(1:5,1:5)
##     1 2 3 4 5
##   1 1 0 0 0 0
##   2 0 1 0 0 0
##   3 0 0 1 0 0
##   4 0 0 0 1 0
##   5 0 0 0 0 1
```

But maybe what you really want is

```
res <- replicate(5000,
          table(sample(x = 0:9, size = 50128, replace = TRUE)))
```

which will create a 5000x10 table of results (in about 130 seconds on my machine)

Finally, the **much** more efficient way to do this would be

```
t(rmultinom(5000,size=50128,prob=rep(1,10)))
```

(0.007 seconds ...)